# How to set the values from the json response to the <p> fields in php and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am developing one web application where, there is one page, with the search bar, where one can search the projects by name. we'll get the list of projects or the desired project just below that search bar. Now when I click on the project name, I want to get the list of team members for that project to be visible just below that project details. I have the following code, I used 'post' call to call the backend and get the list of members for that project and get the result into JSON. Now I want to put these values to the `<p>` tags for that team member information. Following is the code:

In **Index.php**

```
<div id="members" class="list" style="display: none;">
    <div class="result">
        <div class="photo">
            <img>
        </div>
        <div class="team_info">
            <div class="tm">
                <div class="member_name">
                    <h5>Member Name</h5>
                    <p id="member_name"></p>
                </div> 
                <div class="prof">
                    <h5>profession</h5>
                    <p id="mem_profession"></p>
                </div>            
            </div>                 
        </div>
        <div class="contact_button">
            <h4 id="contact">See Contact</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#project_name').on("click",function(){
        $.post('/teamMembers.php', {}, function(res){
            for(var i=0; i < res.length; i++ ){
                $('#member_name').val(res[i]['name']);
                $('#mem_profession').val(res[i]['profession']);
            }
            $('#members').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

In **teamMembers.php** Controller file

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['project_name'])){
            $project_name = $_SESSION['project_name'];

            $members = \Model\Team_Member::getList(['where'=>"project_name = '$project_name'"]);
            $this->toJson($members);
        }
?>
```

I have stored the project name in `$_SESSION` and I get the response of these json request in the following manner:

```
[{
    "name":"ABC",
    "email":"test@test.com",
    "phone":"9874563210",
    "project_name":"Test Project",
    "profession":"student",
    "id":1312
}]
```

After all this code, I am still facing some issues like: I am not able to see the any of the team members details, not even the label, even though I use `.show()` function. Another I am not sure if that was the correct way to set the values to the `<p>` element from the json response. Help is appreciated

Comment: [ID's Must Be Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think I have all unique and different ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paragraphs cannot have values, you need to set the text within them:

```
for(var i=0; i < res.length; i++ ){
    $('#member_name').html(res[i]['name']);
    $('#mem_profession').html(res[i]['profession']);
}
```

OR

```
for(var i=0; i < res.length; i++ ){
    $('#member_name').text(res[i]['name']);
    $('#mem_profession').text(res[i]['profession']);
}
```

If your markup repeats, you need to make sure each element has unique ID's. [ID's Must Be Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

EDIT: I [tested](https://jsfiddle.net/tru77h9q/12/) with the following code. You do not need the `for()` loop (unless you're planning to expand this, at which point the unique ID's come into play):

```
// you do not need the first couple of lines of code, was just used for testing
var json = '[{"name":"ABC","email":"test@test.com","phone":"9874563210","project_name":"Test Project","profession":"student","id":1312}]';
var res = JSON.parse(json);


$('#member_name').html(res[0]['name']);
$('#mem_profession').html(res[0]['profession']);
$('#members').show();
```

EDIT 2: If you have more than one member of a project you can append their data to each paragraph like this:

```
var json = '[{"name":"ABC","email":"test@test.com","phone":"9874563210","project_name":"Test Project","profession":"student","id":1312},{"name":"XYZ","email":"test@test.com","phone":"9874563210","project_name":"Test Project","profession":"teacher","id":1312}]';
var res = JSON.parse(json);
for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    $('#member_name').append(res[i]['name'] + ', ');
    $('#mem_profession').append(res[i]['profession'] + ', ');
}
```

This results in output like this:

> Member Name
>   ABC, XYZ,
>
> profession
>   student, teacher,

Comment: Thanks. But I am still struggling with showing the team members. I have used `style="display: none;"` and used `$('members').show();`, but yet still not able to see the details.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$('#members').show();`, with the ID identifier?

Comment: Yes, I mean to say `$('#members').show();` but still not working

Comment: Only one div with the id "members"

Comment: Can you see this hidden when you inspect the source of the page?

Comment: Is there a link to the page where we can see it?

Comment: Yes I was able to see hidden when I inspect. I tried closing the project, restart the server and it worked. It's wierd I don't know what was the problem. But if I have more than one members in one project than I am not able to see all the members. I am able to see only one. While in response I am getting all the members of that project. Do you think my loop is wrong ?

Comment: No, if you have more than one member then you have to make sure the ID's are unique or you have to append the values to the field.

Comment: Even though I need to show it on the same div's, I need different id's for all the members ? If yes, how can I do that ?

Comment: Have a look at this code: https://jsfiddle.net/tru77h9q/20/ This *appends* data to each paragraph. Is that what you want?

Comment: Something like this, but need to show one members details as one single row not alltogether. One member's details as one record

Comment: More like this https://jsfiddle.net/tru77h9q/22/? At this point it just becomes formatting.

Comment: I will look at the formatting, thanks a lot Jay. I appreciate your help and suggestions. Thanks again

Comment: Glad to help @JohnCaverns